# How do I make a CSS Rotating Animation?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a css rotation animation that has different speeds at different degree points.

Here is the animation I'm trying to make:

[image]

[Here is a Pen](https://codepen.io/imtrent/pen/dKYQgX) of what I currently have and below is the code:

```css
img {
  width: 125px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

#loading {
  -webkit-animation: slow 1.5s linear 1.5s, fast 1s linear 1s, slow2 1s linear 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slow {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg)
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fast {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(91deg)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg)
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slow2 {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(271deg)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="loading" src="https://i.imgur.com/VpLRlbZ.png">
```

Comment: Great plan.  Do you have a question?

Comment: @Simon I'm wondering how to make the animation go different speeds at different degree points. As you can see in the codepen the animation spins, but doesn't really work.

Comment: Hey ianmtrent, to avoid people nitpicking about “how” you asked your question make sure you read [ask] and be sure to make your question conform to [mcve]. Once your questions conform to what the culture here expects, you’ll have much better results.

Answer (score 6):

So, in the example you provided, the effect is only done by modifying the `animation-timing-function` css property.

Then you'll have only one animation

```css
div {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
animation:rotate 3s  infinite;
animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,0,.5,1);
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) } 
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) } 
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can find more informations here : https://callmenick.com/dev/level-up-animations-cubic-bezier/

But the point is, use only one animation and modify speed at different angles value modifying this `animation-timing-function`.

**EDIT** Added a closer cubic bezier timing function thanks to @SirExotic comment.

Comment: Since you already provided the answer, I thought I would come up with the approximate spin-effect he wanted. You can put it in your answer if you wish: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/SirExotic/yv9Lxjo4/38/)

Answer (score 4):

You can just divide the animation keyframes into several ones, and adjust the percentages of each to set the relative speeds:

The *natural* percentage for 90deg would be 25% . Any value higher than that will make this part slower

```css
img {
  width: 125px;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

#loading {
  animation: rotate 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(90deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(270deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="loading" src="https://i.imgur.com/VpLRlbZ.png">
```